# How to access my resource i.e menu through inflate() method?

Tags: android

This is the program i am doing I have created two items in main.xml i.e "About Us" And "Preferences" which i want to use in my program but when i am trying to access the main.xml using inflate method in MenuInflater it cannot find my resource.

```
package com.sagar.firstapp;

import android.R;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[]={"StartingPoint","TextPlay","Email","Camera","Data","example5"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese=classes[position];
        try {
            Class ourclass=Class.forName("com.sagar.firstapp."+cheese);
            Intent ourintent=new Intent(Menu.this,ourclass);
            startActivity(ourintent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowup=getMenuInflater();
        blowup.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);/*Can't find my main.xml   resource*/
        return true;
    }
}
```

here is my main.xml code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item 
     android:title="About Us"   
     android:id="@+id/aboutus"
     android:numericShortcut="1"
     android:alphabeticShortcut="a"/>

    <item 
     android:title="Preferences"   
     android:id="@+id/preferences"
     />
```

R.java(Generated lines)

```
public static final int aboutus=0x7f09001d;
public static final int preferences=0x7f09001e;

public static final class menu {
        public static final int main=0x7f080000;
    }
```

Comment: clean and rebuilt your project..

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. This would include the menu resource (and its path within your project) along with the Java code that is attempting to use this resource.

Comment: I did that still but struggling to run my code @Mohit

Comment: Is your R.java generating?

Comment: post your menu.xml code

Comment: Yes it generating @Mohit

Comment: I have test your code ...i dont see any problem in it...I would suggest to `delete` your `R.java` file then clean-built your project,uninstall your app from device/emulator and reinstall it...

Answer (score 0):

**Create a `main.xml` under res/menu folder**

**main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
    <item  android:id="@+id/item1"  
        android:title="About Us"/>  
    <item  android:id="@+id/item2"  
        android:title="Preferences"/>  

</menu>
```

and in your Activity call `inflate()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu menu)`

```
 @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu  
        return true;  
    }
```

Comment: i am doing that as u can see my code but still its not recognizing

Comment: post your R.java generated Line